# PHP Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded on a 100k row query

Tags: php, mysql

Is it possible to write a php code that will fetch a serialize data, unserialize it and write contents on a new database schema with NO

> ini_set("max_execution_time", 0);

I think I already optimize my codes but that really cannot be avoided.

I use the following code with iteration.

```
$queryCount ="SELECT count(*) FROM APPLICATION where PRO_UID='$PRO_UID' 
                AND APP_STATUS != 'DRAFT' 
                AND APP_STATUS != 'CANCELLED'";
    $resultCount = $mysqli->query($queryCount);
    $count = (mysqli_fetch_array($resultCount));

    for($x=0;$x < $count; $x += 1000){


        $queryData = "SELECT * FROM wf_workflow.APPLICATION 
                        where PRO_UID='$PRO_UID' 
                        AND APP_STATUS != 'CANCELLED' 
                        AND APP_STATUS != 'DRAFT' 
                        not in (SELECT APP_NUMBER FROM export_workflow.CARDS_CONTACT_DETAILS_LOOKUP) LIMIT 2000";


        $resultData = $mysqli->query($queryData);

        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($resultData)){

            $data = unserialize($row['APP_DATA']);
            $APP_NUMBER = $row['APP_NUMBER'];
            $PERSON_NAME = $data["PersonalInformation"][1]["FirstName"] . " " . $data["PersonalInformation"][1]["MiddleName"] ." " . $data["PersonalInformation"][1]["LastName"];
            $MOBILE = $data["ContactDetails"][1]["MobileNo"];
            $OFFICE_PHONE = $data["EmploymentInformation"][1]["OfficeTelNo"];
            $HOME_PHONE = $data["ContactDetails"][1]["TelephoneNo1"];

            $sql = "INSERT INTO CARDS_CONTACT_DETAILS_LOOKUP (APP_NUMBER , HOME_PHONE , MOBILE , OFFICE_PHONE, PERSON_NAME)
                    VALUES ('$APP_NUMBER' , '$HOME_PHONE' , '$MOBILE' , '$OFFICE_PHONE' , '$PERSON_NAME')";

            if (mysqli_query($mysqli, $sql)) {
                echo "New record created successfully FROM dev";
            } else {
                echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . mysqli_error($mysqli);
            }

        }

    echo "finished the dev";

    }
```

Comment: Yes that is possible. Try it

Comment: Is it a one off operation?

Comment: Do you call your script via browser? Consider [calling it via CLI](http://php.net/manual/de/features.commandline.php), that's much faster and can sometimes avoid timeouts.

Comment: Will depend on many factors, but probably yes. How complex is the serialized data?

Comment: I called it via browser and it is a one off operation. How do you do it then?

Comment: Its a long data contains info of clients, the serializing part is no problem it just that everytime I run my script it stops writing on the 400+ entry and shows the error

Comment: Add some debugging in to work out which bits of the processing are taking time. The concentrate on improving the performance of those bits. But without seeing the script there isn't much more I can say.

Comment: added the post with my code

Comment: Looking at that I am not sure why you are looping around the same query multiple times. It appears that you are trying to  process 2000 rows at a time and exclude the rows that have already been processed. But you are using NOT IN (SELECT.....), but not supplying a value / column to check that it isn't in there. Not sure what mysql would do in that situation, but think it will probably check that true / false (ie the result of checking APP_STATUS != 'DRAFT' ) is not returned by the sub query.

Comment: on the while loop, I use it to iterate the serialize data and get the numbers I needed from the clients. Can I do that without looping?

Comment: The while loop looks essential (yes there are ways to return all data as an array, but I see no benefit to you for that, just a far larger memory requirement). It is the for loop I was talking about

Comment: Damn this is driving me nuts. I remove the for loop but the $queryCount already produces 100k rows. I think that is the culprit but I need to extract the mobile numbers on every row

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first query appears to just get a count that is used for the for loop. But the for loop does not appear to be required.

The main query is using *AND APP_STATUS != 'DRAFT' not in (SELECT* which isn't checking a value / column is in the the result set of the sub query. Suspect this will just check if true or false (the result of *APP_STATUS != 'DRAFT'* ) is a returned value from the sub query. Looking at your code I think you meant to have *AND APP_STATUS != 'DRAFT' AND APP_NUMBER not in (SELECT* . However NOT IN can perform quite badly so it might be better to recode it as a join.

Taking this in to account, something like this (not tested):-

```
<?php

    $queryData = "SELECT a.APP_NUMBER, a.APP_DATA 
                    FROM wf_workflow.APPLICATION a
                    LEFT OUTER JOIN export_workflow.CARDS_CONTACT_DETAILS_LOOKUP b
                    ON a.APP_NUMBER = b.APP_NUMBER
                    WHERE a.PRO_UID='$PRO_UID' 
                    AND a.APP_STATUS != 'CANCELLED' 
                    AND a.APP_STATUS != 'DRAFT' 
                    AND b.APP_NUMBER IS NULL";


    $resultData = $mysqli->query($queryData);

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($resultData))
    {

        $data = unserialize($row['APP_DATA']);
        $APP_NUMBER = $row['APP_NUMBER'];
        $PERSON_NAME = $data["PersonalInformation"][1]["FirstName"] . " " . $data["PersonalInformation"][1]["MiddleName"] ." " . $data["PersonalInformation"][1]["LastName"];
        $MOBILE = $data["ContactDetails"][1]["MobileNo"];
        $OFFICE_PHONE = $data["EmploymentInformation"][1]["OfficeTelNo"];
        $HOME_PHONE = $data["ContactDetails"][1]["TelephoneNo1"];

        $sql = "INSERT INTO CARDS_CONTACT_DETAILS_LOOKUP (APP_NUMBER , HOME_PHONE , MOBILE , OFFICE_PHONE, PERSON_NAME)
                VALUES ('$APP_NUMBER' , '$HOME_PHONE' , '$MOBILE' , '$OFFICE_PHONE' , '$PERSON_NAME')";

        if (mysqli_query($mysqli, $sql)) 
        {
            echo "New record created successfully FROM dev";
        } 
        else 
        {
            echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . mysqli_error($mysqli);
        }
    }

    echo "finished the dev";
```

You could also probably improve the performance of the script by batching up the INSERTs (ie, insert say 100 rows at a time). This probably won't make a big difference to the script timing out (time spent waiting for MySQL shouldn't affect the scripts time limit) but might speed it up for you. Something like this:-

```
$queryData = "SELECT a.APP_NUMBER, a.APP_DATA 
                FROM wf_workflow.APPLICATION a
                LEFT OUTER JOIN export_workflow.CARDS_CONTACT_DETAILS_LOOKUP b
                ON a.APP_NUMBER = b.APP_NUMBER
                WHERE a.PRO_UID='$PRO_UID' 
                AND a.APP_STATUS != 'CANCELLED' 
                AND a.APP_STATUS != 'DRAFT' 
                AND b.APP_NUMBER IS NULL";


$resultData = $mysqli->query($queryData);

$inserts = array();

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($resultData))
{

    $data = unserialize($row['APP_DATA']);
    $APP_NUMBER = $row['APP_NUMBER'];
    $PERSON_NAME = $data["PersonalInformation"][1]["FirstName"] . " " . $data["PersonalInformation"][1]["MiddleName"] ." " . $data["PersonalInformation"][1]["LastName"];
    $MOBILE = $data["ContactDetails"][1]["MobileNo"];
    $OFFICE_PHONE = $data["EmploymentInformation"][1]["OfficeTelNo"];
    $HOME_PHONE = $data["ContactDetails"][1]["TelephoneNo1"];

    $inserts[] =  "'$APP_NUMBER' , '$HOME_PHONE' , '$MOBILE' , '$OFFICE_PHONE' , '$PERSON_NAME')";

    if (count($inserts) > 100)
    {
        $sql = "INSERT INTO CARDS_CONTACT_DETAILS_LOOKUP (APP_NUMBER , HOME_PHONE , MOBILE , OFFICE_PHONE, PERSON_NAME)
                VALUES ".implode(', ', $inserts);
        $inserts = array();
        if (mysqli_query($mysqli, $sql)) 
        {
            echo "New records created successfully FROM dev";
        } 
        else 
        {
            echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . mysqli_error($mysqli);
        }
    }
}

if (count($inserts) > 0)
{
    $sql = "INSERT INTO CARDS_CONTACT_DETAILS_LOOKUP (APP_NUMBER , HOME_PHONE , MOBILE , OFFICE_PHONE, PERSON_NAME)
            VALUES ".implode(', ', $inserts);
    $inserts = array();
    if (mysqli_query($mysqli, $sql)) 
    {
        echo "New records created successfully FROM dev";
    } 
    else 
    {
        echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . mysqli_error($mysqli);
    }
}

echo "finished the dev";
```

You might be well advised to escape your data though!

Comment: Hi man thanks for the optimisation. It can now input 2000 entries in just seconds but, it somehow crashes midway because the query is almost 100k+

Comment: Is it crashing on a particular record? Does it crash on a read of the next record or on the insert? Do you have an index on APP_NUMBER on each of the tables? Have you tried MYSQL_USE_RESULT on the select? http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php

Comment: No I haven't. It just reach max time. But thanks for the code it really optimize the execution time

Comment: Might just have to increase the script time limit.

Comment: yes. I think there is no way I can finish that up in 30 secs. I set the limit the only cheat code to go